# remove the 'u' and brackets from text file output - pyspark

Tags: python, formatting

I need to output the values from my spark program into a text file in the following format:

'ADDRESS', VALUE

However, my current output is:

(u'ADDRESS', VALUE)

Is there a way for me to reformat the output so when it is written into the text file is it in the format of the 1st stated format.

Here is my code below:

```
import pyspark
import re
from operator import *

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")


def good_line(line):
    try:
        fields = line.split(',')
        if len(fields)!=7:
            return False

        if int(fields[3]) == 0:
            return false

        str(fields[2])
        int(fields[3])

        return True

    except:
        return False


lines = sc.textFile("/user/ae306/transactions.csv")

clean_lines = lines.filter(good_line)

transactions = clean_lines.map(lambda transaction: (transaction.split(',')[2] ,int(transaction.split(',')[3])))

result = transactions.reduceByKey(add)

print(result)

result.saveAsTextFile("CompEvalSparkPartBJob1TestFile")
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try `print(*result)` for staters, then `print("{}, {}".format(*result))`

Comment: The `u` is a thing of the outdated Python 2. You should consider updating.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but that will not put the results into a text file?

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a `tuple` and printing it prints its string representation as text, which in turn prints the representation of the elements inside it

But the representation of the elements is not the same if you print the elements separately. You have no control on this representation.

Good old `format` would allow this control

```
print("'{}', {}".format(*result))
```

to put this in a text file instead, a handle must be obtained somewhere during initialization (not using the `with` syntax willingly, look it up if needed)

```
f = open("textfile.txt","w")
```

then instead of `print` just `f.write`, with linefeed, as many times as needed (if there are several results)

```
f.write("'{}', {}\n".format(*result))
```

in the end, close the file:

```
f.close()
```

Comment: but that won't put it into the text file? I need the results saved in a text file?

Comment: Same thing, ```text = "'{}', {}".format(*result)``` text variable must be put into a text file.

Comment: of course. This is trivial and could be searched. But what the heck.